# Google sheets IF THEN (Give popup)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

im working on a google sheets project to handle restaurant bookings.

I want to add an error or alert if table bookings for a time range exceed a stated amount.

I have 5 slots per 30mins setup on the sheet, ie, :

```
TIME    Covers
12:00 - 2 
12:00 - 5
12:00 - 
12:00 - 4
12:00 - 3
------------------
12:30 - 1
12:30 - 7
12:30 - 
12:30 - 
12:30 - 3
```

Each time slot has a "covers" column which contain the amount of people for the booking. IF the total for each 30mins amounts to more than 20, i want to show an alert.

Any ideas or suggestions on achieving this?

Comment: From `i want to show an alert.`, if you are thinking the dialog, I think that in this case, how about using Google Apps Script? But in your situation, when do you want to show the alert? And, in your showing sample sheet, for example, `12:00 - 2` is 3 columns "A" to "C" of `12:00`, `-`, and `2`? And, what is `------------------`? I apologize for my poor understanding.

Comment: Write a google script which  runs using the`onOpen` trigger.  The script should loop the time column and determine the start row and end row for each time grouping.  Store those values in a lookup. You will also need to use the `onEdit` trigger to capture any changes in the covers column.  When a change occurs, find the appropriate time grouping using the lookup. Sum the totals in the grouping. If they exceed 20, show a popup using the `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you complete your spreadsheet with a total per slot column and conditional formatting

in C1

```
={"total per slot";arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,sumif(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B)))}
```

[image]